# How to convert OSM file ot PNG tiles on MacOS?

Tags: mac, rendering

Im trying to create an offline map with Leaflet. So I got this package from https://download.geofabrik.de/africa.html Is there any way to convert osm.pbf to PNG tiles on MacOS?

Comment: You'll effectively need to run an OSM server (which you can do, since it's open source), but there's no trivial process. PBF (and XML) files contain "vector data" meaning they tell you where things are and their shapes, but they don't actually contain pixel graphics. Of course, using that data, you could create your own map that looks different from OSM's "standard" tile rendering.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I am working on the same problem ie converting a big OSM map in a series of small PNG or JPG files.

Comment: @SLareau unfortunately we decided to bypass it by redirecting requests for now... this one is needle in the stack as theres not much converters available and well documented for OSX. I would recommend switching to other platforms or using another physical machine as an option